# LESS color themes using Gulp

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, less, concatenation

I'm trying to make different color themes for a website. The output should be theme-colornamehere.css. I'm using LESS and Gulp. I have made this task to get earch file but it's not working. Getting undefined back for file.name and error about variables on compile. All used plugins are installed.

```
gulp.task('defaultTheme', function () {
return gulp.src([
    './style/colors/*.less',
    './style/variables.less',
    './style/general.less'
])
    .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file) {
        return stream
            .pipe(concat('theme-'+ file.name +'.css'))
    }))
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(err) {
        gutil.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(stripCssComments())
    .pipe(gulpif(isLive, cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie9'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./style/dist'))
});
```

Hope you can give me an answer. Thanks

Comment: "error about variables" is not useful. Please edit your question to include the complete error message.

Comment: It's less variables erroring because it can't be read somehow

Comment: What part of this task actually compiles the LESS into CSS?

Comment: Concat does. It combined the files and makes it a theme

Comment: Is `concat` in your code gulp-concat? gulp-concat combines the files, like you say, but it does not convert LESS code to CSS code.

Comment: Yes it is. Yes that's right. The Less pipe is doing that job

Comment: My bad. I didn't see that. What are the actual values of `stream` and `file` inside the `foreach` callback?

Comment: I used this function and example https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foreach maybe I forgot something. If I run gulp now it creates a file theme-undefined.css

Comment: What are the actual values of `stream` and `file` inside the `foreach` callback?

Comment: Good question. Didn't find that out and didn't understand the example that we'll. Thought there was missing something